# Software design problem

Tags: .net, concurrency, local-database

I have an application which will be distributed to a large number of people within my company. I need to have some central data store for this application and dont have the budget for SQL server or anything like this. I noticed that there is a thing called a Local Database in VS2008... will this be suitable for a central data store? the volume of data is not large

thanks!

Note:
I do not have a server to host it on, This is not my choice, its just a condition i have to work under. The best i can get is space on the shared drive

Comment: What sort of data will you be storing?  Will client PCs write to, or just read from, this store?

Comment: Writing to the data store will be infrequent. The data is quite lightweight and basic. XML would be preferable but i dont think all databases will store it.

Comment: you don't have a cheap PC laying somewhere around your company that you can use as DB server?

Comment: Cheap PC i have, and it has SQL server express on it, but Politix i also have, and so am denied this option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you got access to a Web Server at your company.

If the clients only need to read the data you could just serve up an xml file from a well known URL.

Comment: I may be able to pull off a webservice. Only cos that is not under the control of our political DBAs :) thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 7):

[MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/?bydis_dis_index=1) is a free, open source database that you can use as well.

Answer (score 4):

Why not [SQL Server Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/database/)? It's free and fully featured.

Comment: The database will be hosted on a shared drive without SQL express installed. Will this still work? if so, can you point me to somewhere that i can learn more?

Comment: If you want concurrency issues and/or (potential) database corruption, go for the shared drive approach with something like Access - if you're after a decent solution then SQL Server Express will be ideal.

Comment: @TerrorAustralis: Shared file for multiple users will get you only problems (file locking, permissions...). Do it right immediately and install SQL express.

Comment: I guess there is no shared file workaround then :( i'll have the neccessary arguments with the DBAs etc etc to see if i can get an instance installed

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use a file share system I would use an Access database. But there is a good chance you will experience some kinds of file corruption at some stage, and if you have many concurrent users untold bad stuff could happen. Basically a file share database works well for one user on a local PC and that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

There is also Postgres, its a bit more robust than MySQL and is free just the same.

System.data.sqlite is a decent option as well for use with Visual Studio, it is also free (but may not be the best option for a large number of clients, although the setup would be easiest by far).